# Reading old QIC-80 tape using Linux with ftape

Tags: magnetic-tape

I have an old Colorado 250MB tape drive, which connects to the PC's floppy controller, that I'd like to use to read a QIC-80 cartridge.

I know that very old versions of the Linux kernel used to have the `ftape` driver built into them (which would theoretically let me read the raw data from the tape), but I've never actually used it, and I'm not sure how to get it to work properly.

I've connected the tape drive to the PC, booted into Linux, and executed the following:

`$ sudo modprobe ftape`

That seemed to load the `ftape` driver successfully, but I still don't see any new devices under `/dev` that are related to the tape drive, e.g. /dev/qft0.

I then tried the following:

`$ sudo /dev/MAKEDEV ftape`

...but that still didn't create any new devices under `/dev`.  I assume I must be missing something very simple. Does anyone have any previous experience getting `ftape` set up?

Comment: you should actually `modprobe zftape` (note the "z"). That should load ftape as well.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an answer then?

Comment: @tofro Please post this as an answer. There's no requirement for answers to be longer than this, if that's all it takes to answer the question, and if it _does_ answer the question the OP should be able to accept it.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm pretty sure it isn't the full answer and would like to see some  confirmation from Dmtry. modprobing the wrong module doesn't explain why MAKEDEV doesn't work properly.

Comment: (I'm away for a couple of days, but will try this suggestion as soon as I get back)

Comment: And... that did the trick!  Running `modprobe zftape` caused the devices to appear, and I was able to read the tape!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Credit goes to @tofro for the answer)
The actual command to activate `ftape` is:

`$ sudo modprobe zftape`

This loads both `zftape` and `ftape`, and creates all the necessary devices under `/dev`, so there's no need to run `MAKEDEV`.

Answer (score 2):

To verify that the module has loaded, use `cat /proc/devices` and verify that there is an entry for device 27.

Once that has worked, use `sudo /dev/MAKEDEV qft` to create the device special files if they are not present.